# How to implement an file storage service in PHP (compatible with S3 or similar)

Tags: php, api, service, amazon-s3

Is there a way to create the server side of something similar to S3, iDrive, Dropbox, etc in strictly PHP?  The end goal would be to allow users to map a drive or folder to our servers using an app that already exists for one of those popular services.

In other words, I don't really want to write the client on the OS side, but rather implement some type of standard (or popular) API so that our server would be compatible with existing apps.

If there is a standard API interface, that would be great too - as long as there are some client apps available for it.  I have tried to search but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Hmm. PHP is not the optimal language for this for a number of reasons. Have you looked into running a WebDAV server on your server?

Comment: Thank you.  I found a PHP WebDAV implementation for PHP that actually seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that comes to standard and works the way you describe is [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav) or maybe [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP).

However, FTP is an insecure and dated protocol, while WebDAV is difficult to support on Windows because of proprietary extensions to the protocol.